# How to change the width of individual table cells (<td>)

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm creating a very complex table and I want to know how to change the width of an individual table cell without affecting the other cells in the column.

```
<table border="1" class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td width="25%"><b>SURNAME</b></td>
        <td width="25%"><b>First Names</b></td>
        <td width="10%"><b>Decorations</b></td>
        <td width="20%"><b>Current Appointment</b></td>
        <td width="5%"><b>Date</b></td>
        <td width="15%"><b>File Number</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="10%"><b>Department</b></td>
        <td width="10%"><b>Geographical location</b></td>
        <td width="15%"><b>Substantive Appointment</b></td>
        <td width="5%"><b>Date</b></td>
        <td width="10%"><b>Terms of Engagement</b></td>
        <td width="55%"><table class="table table-condensed text_size">
            <thead class="text-gray-b">
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Date Entry Made</b></td>
                    <td><b>Salary Scale</b></td>
                    <td><b>Basic Salary p.a.</b></td>
                    <td><b>Indicement Pay p.a.</b></td>
                    <td><b>Date paid from</b></td>
                    <td><b>M.</b></td>
                    <td><b>Yr</b></td>
                    <td><b>AUTHORITY</b></td>
                    <td><b>Signature (Certified By)</b></td>
                    <td><b>Name Stamp (Certified By)</b></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><b></b></td>
                    <td><b></b></td>
                    <td><b></b></td>
                    <td><b></b></td>
                    <td><b></b></td>
                    <td><b></b></td>
                    <td><b></b></td>
                    <td><b></b></td>
                    <td><b></b></td>
                    <td><b></b></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

For example now I tried using the 'width' attribute to change the widths of two cells in the same column (SURNAME & Department), but it seems the size of the cells in the same column can't have different widths.

Is there a way for table cells (td) in the same column to have different widths?

Comment: I think that the columns take the width of the column with the biggest width.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried colspan attribute of the td element , you can use numbers like 1 and 2 etc
 when you need the td to take width of 2 columns etc

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible - the special thing (layout-wise) about a table is exactly that, that all cells in a column will always automatically have the same width and all cells in a row will always automatically have the same height.

The only (kind of...) exception are `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes inside the `td` tags which determine that that particular cell takes the space of itself *and* the subsequent cell/s (depending on the number value in that attribute). However, then you have to be careful to put accordingyl *less*  cells in a row or column, so that the overall number stays the same (regular cells counted as 1, the others by their `colspan` or `rowspan` value)